# How to insert <img> tag, or JS script through textContent?

Tags: javascript, image, web, forum

I am looking for a way to insert JS script or Image tags with textContent.

There is a point on the site where I get a paragraph by

```
var game = document.getElementById("SomethingCool");
```

and to do

```
game.textContent = "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/GOO9vOH.png' alt='' height='42' width='42' id='ball'>"
```

but it will show the text and not an image because it's a string, so how can I insert the image? 
same for JS scripts.

thanks :D

Comment: use `innerHTML` instead on `textContent` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML.

Comment: You've tagged this question with jQuery. Are you using jQuery or do you want vanilla?

Comment: The entire reason for `textContent`'s existence is to *not add or manipulate HTML*. Well, aside from the content but it will not just create other DOM nodes.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was quick, it works! how do I mark it as solved? and I am ok with both vanilla and Jquary

Comment: You can delete the question. It is not really useful for others than yourself

Comment: jQuery: `$("#SomethingCool").html("<img src='https://i.imgur.com/GOO9vOH.png' alt='' height='42' width='42' id='ball' />")`